# How to code a generic Swift class which stores a Generator of the same type

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to write a class which handles objects of a homogenous type, and I'd like to feed in those objects using an (otherwise arbitrary) Generator of the same type.

In essence this:

```
class MyGenericClass<T> {
  var source : GeneratorType
  var itemsProcessed = [ T ]()

  init(source: GeneratorType) {
    self.source = source
  }

  func getValue() -> T? {
    let item = source.next()
    if let item = item {
      itemsProcessed.append(item)
    }
    return item
  }
}
```

Which you could call like that:

```
let myThing = MyGenericClass([ 1, 2, 3].generate())
let first   = myThing.getValue()
```

This raises the: 'GeneratorType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.

Tried a few things (e.g. `GeneratorType<T>`) but I can't figure out how to do this right.
How does one tell the GeneratorType that T is its Element type alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the generator type as the type placeholder `G`,
and refer to its element type as `G.Element`:

```
class MyGenericClass<G : GeneratorType> {
    var source : G
    var itemsProcessed : [ G.Element ] = []

    init(source: G) {
        self.source = source
    }

    func getValue() -> G.Element? {
        let item = source.next()
        if let item = item {
            itemsProcessed.append(item)
        }
        return item
    }
}

let myThing = MyGenericClass(source: [ 1, 2, 3].generate())
let first   = myThing.getValue()
println(first) // Optional(1)
```

Optionally, define a type alias for the element type:

```
class MyGenericClass<G : GeneratorType> {

    typealias T = G.Element

    var source : G
    var itemsProcessed : [ T ] = []

    // ...
}
```

Comment: One more thing (new Q, not sure ;-) I have another type which is like a Generator, and can wrap into a Gen. I was thinking I can do this: ```convenience init<T: MyOtherType where T.Element == G.Element>(source: T) { init(MyOtherType.wrapInGenerator(source)) }```. Where wrapInGenerator is a a Generator matching G. But apparently the T.Element == G.Element is insufficient to let the compiler know about the alias. Is there another trick for this? P.S.: Works fine for sequences ```init<S: SequenceType where S.Generator == G>(_ source: S) { self.init(source.generate()) }```